# Proving the Probability of a Subset

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn probability and came across the following question. The conclusion proposed seems obvious but I am unsure on how to approach it. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Suppose that A and B are two events such that $A \subset B$. Show that $P(A) \leq P(B)$.**

I believe that I am supposed to start with the following rule but am not sure how to apply it in this case. 
If A and B are two events in S, then $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B')$.

Comment: Monotonicity can be proven by Kolmogorov's [probability axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Monotonicity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $C$ be the set $B\setminus A$. (Recall that $B\setminus A$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x\in B$ but $x\not\in A$.) Then $B=A\cup C$ and $A\cap C=\emptyset$.